# How to not automatically add dates that are not in the original data when using datetime type values on the X axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

When plotting a `DataFrame` value with `datetime` type on the `X axis` and `int` type value on the `Y axis` with `matplotlib`, a date axis that is not included in the original `DataFrame` type value is also added as shown in the image below

*the original data does not have data for `June 5`, but it is added to the plotted graph.

How can I avoid including date data not included in the original data in the graph?

[image]

---

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 1)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 2)
d3 = datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 3)
d4 = datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 4)
d6 = datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 6)
d7 = datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 7)

df = pd.DataFrame({'created_at': [d1, d2, d3, d4, d6, d7],
                   'price': [100, 200, 400, 350, 180, 30]})

x1 = df.created_at
y1 = df.price

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)


ax.plot(x1,y1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

---

python 3.10

jupyter 1.0.0

matplotlib.pyplot 3.7.1

Comment: It's a **continuous** datetime axis. That's the expected behavior of any type of continuous axis.

Comment: If you just want the dates treated as categories, you can change them to strings

Comment: @JodyKlymak in general, this is not a good idea: 1. every single date will be plotted on the x-axis, which is terrible for large data, 2. the spacing between each point will be uniform, even if the distance between dates is not uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with Matplotlib [set_xticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html):

```py
# Add the following line after your code
ax.set_xticks(df.created_at)
```

Which gets you:

[image]

Otherwise, you can plot `y1` only and use [set_xticklabels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html):

```py
ax.plot(y1)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.created_at.dt.day)
```

Then:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
With this method, the `05` tick labels are not displayed, but the space is used.
Is it possible to skip this space and shrink it?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternate solution. Cheers.